# How to call a django queryset using a string?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Lets say I want to run this query on a model called `Person`:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I want to run it using a string. Something like this:

```
person = getattr(Person, 'objects.get(pk=1)')()
```

This does not work, but hopefully it clearly conveys the idea. I know I can just run `eval`, but its apparently dangerous. What is the **safest** way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the use case for this? I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 1):

The safest reply I think needs to start with "don't". You seem to be trying to write a way to take unknown input and run it against your database, and *that* is what is dangerous (hence why eval is dangerous too, though that's much more dangerous). You need to validate the user input before using it to construct your query. Ideally, the situations in which you accept user input should be constrained enough that you can handle all options with if statements and other clear logic.

That said, there are times when this might be appropriate. "getattr" only gets immediate attributes of the given object, in your case, the "objects" attribute of Person, then from the result of that you can get the "get" attribute, which will then be a function you can call. Something like "getattr(getattr(Person, 'object'), 'get')(pk=1)"

Why can't you just store the requested I'd in a variable, say i, then just run Person.objects.get(pk=i) like normal? The fact that you're asking this question indicates that you might not be familiar enough with Python to understand the dangers and safety mechanisms necessary to safely do something this dynamic, but it's really rare that you actually need to. If you provided more information about the problem you're actually trying to solve, it's likely someone here could give you a much safer and better solution.